# remote debugging in visual studio cannot connect

Tags: visual-studio, azure, remote-debugging

Hello i have a problem with remote debugging in Visual Studio (v12)
I Created windows azure account i published application to the cloud.
Then i connected to this account through remote desktop. Address of remote computer is f.e Iron.app.net
Then i downloaded there and run remote debugger. I started msvsmon.exe and it created server named:
RD0015555E2:555
And now i would like to remote debugging in my host.
i know i must attach to process. And i do it.
From Visual Studio: Debug->attach to process->Qualifier:RD0015555E2  and it cannot resolve host name.
 i also tried Iron.app.net but then it shows error that it seems that msvsmon is not installed.
I dont know what should i type into Qualifier (as remote machine)?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2011/02/01/windows-azure-emulators-on-your-desktop.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 0):

Remote debugging is tricky to configure Windows Azure Cloud Services. Other options that you have are:

- [Intellitrace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/06/07/using-intellitrace-to-debug-windows-azure-cloud-services.aspx) (in case you've got Visual Studio Ultimate)
- Intensive (verbose) pro-active code instrumentation (logging) from the beginning.
- [Profiling Cloud Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh369930.aspx#BK_ProfilingCloudService)

Chose either, and watch your logs/traces.

Or deep dive into [Remote Debugging Cloud Services](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Remote-Debugging-Windows-dedaaec9). I would, however use Remote Debugging as a final option, when everything else does not work and does not help me. Typically most of the issues that would pop in the cloud will also pop in when debugging locally. And if role is just recycling, you will not be able to attach debugger at all.

Comment: solved. i shoulded create vpn.because remote debugging is not allowed through internet